# Plot tree using test data in R

Tags: r, plot, tree

I fitted a decision tree using the R package `prp`. I'm able to plot the tree using `rpart.plot()`, but it shows train data.

```
fitTree <- rpart(target ~ ., data=datTrainSel, method="class", 
ml <- fitTree

png(paste0(outputPath, paste(c("cp", prefix), collapse = "_"), '.png', collapse=''), 
width=1200, height=1600, res=300)
rpart.plot(ml)
dev.off()
```

How can I plot the decision tree using test data?

Comment: I would advise you to post the code (along with sample data) which you tried. Thanks!

Comment: @Prem I added the code!

Comment: Code seems to be incomplete :)... Anyway instead of plotting tree on test data usually prediction is calculated on it `test_pred <- predict(fitTree, test, type='class')` and then confusion matrix is built to check the accuracy of classification model i.e. `conf_mat <- table(test_pred, test$target)` `sum(diag(conf_mat))/sum(conf_mat)`.

Comment: I know how to obtain confusion matrix and check for accuracy and other metrics, but I need to plot the tree...

Comment: What I meant is that you can't plot test data tree using the tree you modeled on train data. `prp()` or `rpart.plot()` expect the `rpart()` output as it's parameter but on test data you don't have such thing as you use `predict()` on it. For more info on plot implementation pls refer - https://github.com/cran/rpart.plot/blob/master/R/prp.R